# hashcat with pepper

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat

During password auditing, I found the pepper key used along the salt during password hashing. I want to know how can I crack it using hashcat/oclhashcat?

As far as I can tell, this are the following format hashcat support:

- `sha256($pass.$salt)`
- `sha256($salt.$pass)`

What I will like to have are:

- `sha256($pass.$salt.**$pepper**)`
- `sha256($salt.$pass.**$pepper**)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the pepper is the same for all passwords, you can use a [hybrid attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hybrid_attack) with a dictionary and a static mask (consisting of the pepper) to cover the second case. Alternatively, you could use a [mask attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack) with a mask ending in the static characters of the pepper.

For the first case, just add the pepper to the input file such that

```
<salt>:<hash>
```

turns into

```
<pepper><salt>:<hash>
```